# Using window in AngularJS to access iframe contents

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a iframe which return some json string. I have to use that json to construct a table.

```
<iframe id="idHiddenFrame" name="HiddenFrame" src="/PTO/PlattsIncident.nsf/frmBlank?ReadForm" width="0px" height="0px" onload="addAttachment()"></iframe>
```

Below is the javascript code using angular js

```
$window.addAttachment=function(){
        if($.parseJSON(frames["HiddenFrame"].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML)!=null){
            $scope.attachments.push($.parseJSON(frames["HiddenFrame"].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML));
            console.log($scope.attachments);
        }
    }
```

console.log is printing the correct value as below

```
0: Object
attachName: "Root Cause Analysis - Stringer SSF - 02072013.doc"
docID: "290005B6A4CFB9FD85257BBB002433A8"
```

But below code using ng-repeat is not working

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="attachment in attachments">{{attachment.attachName}}</li>
</ul>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try below code and used $scope.$apply():

```
$window.addAttachment=function(){
        if($.parseJSON(frames["HiddenFrame"].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML)!=null){
            $scope.attachments.push($.parseJSON(frames["HiddenFrame"].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML));
            console.log($scope.attachments);
           $scope.$apply();
        }
    }
```